# two-way handshake and three-way handshake

Tags: networking

I was reading a book about computer network written by Tanenbaum specifically about handshaking. In there he explains two-way handshake is not enough, considering this case:

A wants to transfer money to B, so A sends a SYN to B, and then B sends an ACK to A. Connection is established and then A can send his money and then drop the connection after it's done. If there is a delayed duplicate SYN from A to B, B will send its ACK again and A will be transferring its money again.

That is one of the weakness of two-way handshake based on the book written by Tanenbaum if I understands it right. The book says three-way handshake can solve this problem.

With a delayed duplicate SYN from A, B sends an ACK and SYN which get rejected by A. This is where I don't get it, it's as if "Hey B why do you send me a SYN and ACK? Oh I know, this is from a delayed SYN, I should just drop it.". Why not, in two-way handshake, A doesn't know that the ACK is made by a delayed duplicate SYN?

Thanks.

Comment: *A* book? Which book? Chapter? Verse?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To establish a connection, the three-way (or 3-step) handshake occurs:

1. SYN: The active open is performed by the client sending a SYN to the server. The client sets the segment's sequence number to a random value A.
2. SYN-ACK: In response, the server replies with a SYN-ACK. The acknowledgment number is set to one more than the received sequence number i.e. A+1, and the sequence number that the server chooses for the packet is another random number, B.
3. ACK: Finally, the client sends an ACK back to the server. The sequence number is set to the received acknowledgement value i.e. A+1, and the acknowledgement number is set to one more than the received sequence number i.e. B+1.

At this point, both the client and server have received an acknowledgment of the connection. The steps 1, 2 establish the connection parameter (sequence number) for one direction and it is acknowledged. The steps 2, 3 establish the connection parameter (sequence number) for the other direction and it is acknowledged. With these, a full-duplex communication is established.

Comment: What changes if the 3rd ACK is not there? Server does not gets a confirmation that client has got SYN-ACK; the client would retry; at which point the server can detect this SYN as a duplicate and send SYN-ACK again; again lost; client again retries. See if reverse channel is unreliable, then the connection is not going anywhere as it is.

The sequence numbers can be exchanged with two messages. 

Reliable transmission is misunderstood. Reliability does NOT, by any stretch of imagination, dictate that AFTER a connection the data would flow through 100% time. The connection may get dropped, no?

Comment: The definition of reliability with regards to TCP is not about connection stability as that is out of the control of the protocol. It is that messages will reliably arrive at the destination application in order.

Comment: Right. So why the third ack is needed. If we omit that, the sequence number scheme can still guarantee in order delivery

Answer (score 9):

According to Kurose and Ross's "Computer Networking: A top-down approach", 6th Edition, p. 232,

> The first two segments carry no payload, that is, no application-layer data; the third of these segments may carry a payload. Because three segments are sent between the two hosts, this connection-establishment procedure is often referred to as a **three-way handshake**

In other words, A does not need to wait for the three-way handshake to complete before sending data.  Only B needs to wait for the three-way handshake to complete.

And why does B need to wait? As [S. Richmond](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23774096/1048186) says, B needs to know that A has received its sequence number before it starts sending data.

Answer (score 0):

The three-way handshake is necessary because both parties need to synchronize their segment sequence numbers used during their transmission.

So, they(in turn) send a SYN segment with a sequence number set to a value n, which then is acknowledged by the other party via a ACK segment with a sequence number set to n+1.

Suppose that client does not send ACK(case of 2 way handshake). Now there might exist a case where seq number of client is not synchronized, but the server will assume that it is synchronized. This could cause a problem.